# How to specify the desired WMS version in Quantum GIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

How can i set a WMS version of layer which i want to display. I am asking because some WMS addresses are still served via older versions like 1.1.1.

In short, I am looking for the equivalent of this one from ArcGIS:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can add it to the URL.
For instance like this:
http://yourserver/wms.php**?VERSION=1.3.0**

Comment: In my case when using geoserver 2.11.1 (June, 2017) there is a bug, because a shapefile with EPSG 4326, QGIS wan't display the wms, but when setting the version to 1.1.0 or 1.1.1 it works. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

When you create your a connection link to your WMS layer you build the parameters (if the process is manual) so you can add the version that you pretend to your metadata information and then pass to your URL. For example....
http//localhost/yyyy/yyy/yyy&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0

Good luck,
José Santos